# Login start problem

Tags: 12.04, login, lts

After years of no problems with my Ubuntu 12.04, today my laptop began experiencing the following problem. When I get to the login screen, it apparently freezes. Regardless, I type my password and hit Enter. Nothing happens. I wait like a minute or a minute and a half and suddenly the password shows in the box (I mean, the dots representing the password) and the machine resumes the login process and operates normally. How do I troubleshoot this problem? Your help is appreciated.

Here's some info about my machine:

```
williepabon@williepabon-VGN-N130G:~$ uname -a
Linux williepabon-VGN-N130G 3.2.0-61-generic-pae #92-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 1 00:10:04 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
williepabon@williepabon-VGN-N130G:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version: core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise
williepabon@williepabon-VGN-N130G:~$ grub-install -v
grub-install (GRUB) 1.99-21ubuntu3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience seems similar except my system is running UbuntuStudio on a HP Pavilion g6, Core i7, Radeon GPU....

```
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS username tty1
username login: username
Password: ********
Last login: Thu May  1 12:26:17 EST 2014 on tty1
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-61-lowlatency x86_64)

 * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

username@username:~$
```

I've tried xstart and reinstalled from a fresh dl of 12.04.4. It has worked for about one day then ends up with tty1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

The same for me. I use Xubuntu 12.04.4 LTS x64, and I never had a problem until I upgraded the kernel to `3.2.0-61`. I use a NVIDIA GTX 660 that worked perfectly with proprietary drivers (CUDA included).
I am trying to downgrade the kernel, but I don't know yet if that is the final solution. Other solutions like start with `nomodeset` or with `acpi_osi=Linux` didn't work for me. I think we should wait for a new revision of the kernel.